# Microphone refuses to work (Kubuntu 15.04)

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have a headset that has a built in microphone [(these)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OUX6U6G), with a single line that is supposed to connect to the computer via the headphone jack. I've tested ti on my android phone, and it can record my voice just fine. However, it does not work on my desktop running Kubuntu 15.04. When I run alsamixer, I have automute disabled, and the front-microphone and front-mic boost levels are above zero. When I run pavucontrol and look at inputs, it says that the front-mic is unplugged when I have my headphones plugged into the headphone jack. If I plug my headphones into the front or rear mic-jacks, they are detected and my voice can just barely be recorded, but obviously I don't want to do this because then I can't get any audio out through the headphones. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?